# Java Graph Implementation: nullpointerexception

Tags: java, arraylist, graph, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement a graph in Java using an `arrayList` of `arrayList`.

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` whenever the `addEdge` function is called. I cannot seem to figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Graph {

    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList;

    public Graph(int vertices){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
            adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
    }

    public void addEdge(int source, int destination){
        adjList.get(source).add(destination);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Graph g = new Graph(4);
        g.addEdge(0, 1);
        g.addEdge(0, 2);
        g.addEdge(1, 2);
        g.addEdge(2, 0);
        g.addEdge(2, 3);
        g.addEdge(3, 3);

        System.out.println("Neighbors of vertex 0: " + adjList.get(0));
        System.out.println("Neighbors of vertex 2: " + adjList.get(2));
    }
}
```

Please kindly advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

In your `Graph` constructor, you're not initializing the `static` member `adjList`, but rather are defining a local one with the same name. Also, there's no need `adjList` to be `static`, because it will be shared among all instances of `Graph`.

Adjust it to:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList;

public Graph(int vertices){
    adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `static` in `adjList` field declaration.

This modifier makes `adjList` a static instance which refers to `null`. 
And in the constructor you instantiate value for another `adjList` that is local for your constructor (and is subject to be gathered by GC after the constructor is called). It is two completely *different* variables with the *same* name

Answer (score 0):

change your constructor so that you are not declaring a local adjList variable

```
public Graph(int vertices){
    adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
        adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

}
```

Also make this adjList variable non static since you want the adjList to be unique to each graph and not shared across all of them

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Graph constructor, you declare an adjList variable, which is in conflict with your static class.
You should replace

```
public Graph(int vertices){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
            adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }

    }
```

by

```
public Graph(int vertices){
        adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < vertices; i++){
            adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }

    }
```